# PHP- How to hide the passing variables in another page

Tags: php

I am new in PHP, I made several folders for different class and section. How to hide the passing variables in another page, I don't want to display it to anyone such that no one can direct access class or section.

Example : -

```
<a href="abc.php?ClassID=<?=$row['Class']?>&SubjectID=<?=$row['SubjectID']?>&SectionName=<?=$row['SectionName']?>&SubjectName=<?=$row['SubjectName']?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon icon-left">
  <i class="entypo-pencil"></i>
  Edit
</a>
```

I want to display it as abc.php, how can I do that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try POST method. or access it using ID.

Comment: you cannot post via links. you need to use form submit else use ajax

Comment: simple pass any unique id of data instead of passing all the data .

Comment: POST would put the variables in a different part of the request, not on the URL.  But they'd still be part of the request.  You can't prevent users from making requests to your application, you can only respond to those requests accordingly.  What's the actual goal here?  What specifically do you want to accomplish/prevent/etc.?

Comment: What you want is impossible. Get comfortable with the idea that *something* has to be shown in a URL or elsewhere to make it unique and allow users to retrieve specific data.

Answer (score -1):

You can call a function and pass it as arguments and call the abc.php inside the function